# Some Icons in Glyphycon displayed as a "" in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3's Glyphicon,
Some icons such as glyphicon-fire, glyphicon-calendar is displayed as "" in Firefox but it's working fine in Chrome.

I'm very sure the fonts and css's location is right,
I've tried every package of bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/ and github, but none of them worked.

Please tell me how can I fix this issue, thanks.

P.S: it's getting weird, the icon-calendar is displayed when I press ctrl-f5, but when I f5 it's displayed as "" again.

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. What have you declared your document's character set as?

Comment: @AndréDion Yep. Thought about the same thing. Check my answer below, `utf-8` is the solution for most languages anyway.

Comment: Does the bootstrap documentation page that has all the icons listed work for you? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 2.3 glyphicons were an image, but in V3, they're made into an icon font.

I can only think of one problem, and it's the charset.

Make sure you have `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your page.

If that's not enough, assuming you're using Apache2 as your webserver, create a `.htaccess` file in your site directory containing this

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer dude, but still not working on my pc, don't know if it's happening on other pc,
but I don't think charset is the issue, because it only happens in some icons.

Comment: Can you link to your site so we can check?

Comment: @user2469629 And are you developing locally or on server?

Comment: I'm developing it locally, should I upload the file somewhere ?

Comment: @user2469629 Try uploading your project somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

The only workaround that I know of is to make images of what you wan't though there might be other simpler ways of doing it.

If you are on a mac then you can open it in chrome and take a small screenshot of it before editing it so that it looks good

If you are on a windows machine then you will need to make a big screenshot or zoom in and make a screenshot from up close

Comment: Yuck. This kind of solution defeats the purpose of using Bootstrap in the first place.